# Are automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^2$ 4-transitive?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given two set of four points, both of them not colinear, is there always $g\in Aut(\mathbb{P}^2)$ such that it sends one set two the other?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez The given problem is _not_ equivalent to the one you stated.  A point in $\mathbb{P}^2$ corresponds to a _line_ in $\mathbb{C}^3$.

Comment: Why is that equivalent? In the case of $\mathbb{P}^1$ the problem is true for two groups of three points. But it is false that you can map each set of three non zero vectors to three non zero vectors that span $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Right! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, given two sets of four non-colinear points you can send one set unto the other **unless** one set has three colinear points and the other hasn't, in which case the impossibility is clear.
Transitivity in the general  case (no three points colinear) is solved by consideration  of the notion of *projective frame*. See Théorème (3.2.1) [here](https://cboumaths.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/m309.pdf).
The remaining case of transitivity (when exactly three points are colinear in each set) is even easier.

Comment: Another question related. Does the automorphisms preserve other algebraic relation of the points? For example, if six points are on a conic, the six points in the image will be lying on a conic too?

Comment: @jiyanez: yes, because the degree of a curve is preserved under projective transformations .

Answer (score 2):

Georges gave a reference; let me sketch the proof to show that it is easy.

First, given three non-collinear points, you can always take them by a projective transformation to the three coordinate points $[1,0,0], \, [0,1,0], \, [0,0,1]$. This is just the fact that any two bases of a vector space are related by a linear transformation.

After doing that, since the fourth point is not collinear with any two of the others, it must have coordinates $[x,y,z]$ with all of $x, \, y, \,z$ nonzero. But now just apply the matrix $\operatorname{diag} \left(\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z} \right)$.